# Best Practice for running hourly backups on an SQL Azure Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I need to backup my production database each hour to the least as it contains a lot of financial information. I've looked into SQL Data Sync but considering the fast pace of schema changes we do all the time, it won't do the trick.

This article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156170.aspx presents a few methods of achieving this but i couldn't figure out which one is better: **Database Copy** or **Import/Export Service (.bacpac)**.

Another thing i came across is a technique for Database Mirroring across different datacenters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj870961.aspx isn't there an easier way to do it? Why do i even need it if Azure has automated backups? (Assuming they do have it).

My question is **what's the best way to do it?**

*Features i'm looking for:*

1. The process has to be entirely automated.
2. I don't want to write new code / scripts to achieve the automation.
3. This has to be reliable and the backup has to be simple to recover.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a good question about db backup/restore on Azure's SQL service, but it's not programming-related. It should be migrated to ServerFault.

Comment: Ok i'm moving it there thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Best Way" is going to get this closed as opinionative but I can tell you that we use the I/E Services and dump a bacpac file and it works well.

Backups are stored in Blob Storage and are easily accessed.

It's also easy to use the Import/Export data-tier functionality in SQL Server to pull a bacpac down and import it directly into your local/dev sql server instance.

Features wise...

1. Process is completely automated - we've a nightly job that does it and the bacpac is just there each morning.
2. You won't have to write code - have a look here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx
3. It's very easy to recover - bacpacs are stored in Blob Storage and can be restored to local via Import Export Data-Tier or restored to Azure via the management portal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i didn't see a way to make the exports run on an hourly basis. The maximum frequency i could set was to once a day. Got an idea?

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need to create a batch job on a local server/azure VM to do it more frequently. There's a tool called SQLPackage.exe that comes with SSMS 2012 that allows you to automate exports. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=VS.103).aspx - There's a sample command line here - http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/